# Conditionals in Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am fairly new to ASP MVC and was wondering what is the best way to handle conditional statements in your views? I am sure there isn't a one size fits all approach, but for simple checks is it wise to have If-Then-Else statements littering the view?

For example, say I have a list and wish to set the class on one of the list items if one of the model properties is set.

```
<% if (myModel.MyProperty == 1) { %>
   <li class="myClass">
<% } else { %>
   <li>
<% } %>
```

Is this the best way to approach this, or is there a better way? I am just concerned that if you have numerous conditionals like this in your view it is going to start to look pretty messy.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a cleaner view, you could create a helper:

```
public static class MyHelpers {
    // Need a more descriptive name (based on what you're generating)
    public static string MyListItemHelper(this HtmlHelper helper, bool condition) {
        if(condition) {
            return "<li class=\"myClass\">";
        } else {
            return "<li>";
        }
    }
}
```

Then your view is just:

```
<%= Html.MyListItemHelper(myModel.MyProperty == 1) %>
    ...
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put this in your controller. Assuming you don't mind having

```
<li class="">
```

Comment: I would _not_ put this in the controller. Setting things like css classes is display logic and doesn't belong in the controller. Keep it in the view I say.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <% foreach (var item in Model.Items) { <%
    <li<%= item.HasProperty ? " class="\class\"" : "" %>>
        <%= Html.Encode(item.Name) %>
    </li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: That works well. Now, let's say you have a list of 10 items (or even more) if you used the method you mention above you will have that conditional in every single list item. For list item 1 if model.property ==1 then set class, if item 2 has property of 2, etc. Isn't thid going to be a little messy?

Comment: with repitive items you probably will use loops with one li element