# Is it clean to have conditional statements within Codeigniter views?

Tags: php, codeigniter, coding-style

I am currently trying to separate my Views as much as possible from my Controllers. Ideally I would like to have minimal PHP in my view, except variable names, etc. These variables are being passed in from the controller.

But is it clean to have `IF` statements (or the like) within a view?

For example

```
// Controller 

$data['status'] = 'pass';

$this->load->view("Status Page", $data);
```

And ..

```
<!-- View -->
<div>
    <?php if($status === 'pass') { ?>
    <img src='passIcon.jpg'>Pass
    <?php } else { ?>
    <img src='failIcon.jpg'>Fail
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

The closest thing I found to an answer on SO was 
[Conditionals in Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709287/conditionals-in-views)

This was for ASP, and I guess the principles still apply. I could bring the conditional statements back into the controller, but then the controller would be creating HTML and sending it to the view, which isn't right either.

Is there any way to avoid this cross over? Or will there always be fragments of PHP in views?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From my point of view, it's the view's job to render the data , so if you need conditions to display it proprely then by all means do it , as it will avoid duplicate html code to split it in 2 views and test the var in the controller .

Allso another good practice would be to use the alternative syntax in the view as it makes following gode much easyer . Eg :

```
<!-- View -->
<div>
    <?php if ( $status === 'pass' ) : ?>
        <img src='passIcon.jpg'>Pass
    <?php else : ?>
        <img src='failIcon.jpg'>Fail
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

---

However taking you're example a bit further you can have the src set in the controller ( i must admit that there will be times where you'll need conditional in views ) :

Controller

```
$data['src'] = ( $data['status'] === 'pass' ) ? 'passIcon.jpg' : 'failIcon.jpg';
$data['text'] = ( $data['status'] === 'pass' ) ? 'Pass text' : 'Fail text';

$this->load->view("Status Page", $data);
```

View

```
<!-- View -->
<div>
    <img src='<?php echo $src; ?>'><?php echo $text; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks poelinca. I like the second option. It does seem like it comes down to the situation, and I do like the line 'so if you need conditions to display it proprely then by all means do it'

Comment: @Poelinca Dorin, thanks for the post. So what about a navigation bar with built in login prompt. Would it be ok to check the "logged in" session variable within the controller and load two separate navbars. ie, navbar_logged_in.php or navbar_logged_out.php depending on whether the user is logged in/out? Of course this creates redundant code within the views. However it sticks with the architectural principle of reusable code. I'm thinking the view should just contain the code to distinguish whether the user is logged in/out and display the login form appropriate, ie deal with the display data

Answer (score 1):

Different frameworks have different accepted practices; in Django, for example, it's frowned on to put any logic in template files.

I've always preferred to keep the controller relatively clutter-free though - especially if it's something as simple as choosing between two images to display.

Ultimately, it's your choice, but for me, simple conditionals and loops are fine in templates.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @John McCollum. I try to keep the controllers clutter free too, but also the views, but also the models. It's a shame there isn't a rug that the clutter can be swept under.

Comment: Looks like we need a new design pattern - model, view, controller, clutter :D